# Run a command which has a file parameter when the file path passed contains non-ASCII characters

Tags: external-calls, character-encoding, run

I want to do run a Linux command from a Mathematica notebook. I see, that Mathematica and my Linux operating system use different character coding.

The problem is that the directories and the file names in my file system also use non-ASCII characters (which is legal in Unix).

According to the Unix command `locale`, I have `LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"`.
According to Mathematica, `$CharacterEncoding` returns me `"UTF-8"`.

(Btw: in the documentation WRI speaks about `"UTF8"` and `"UTF-8"`. **Is there any difference?** If both are synonymous and if really both forms have to be used somewhere in Mathematica commands or options, **would it be possible** to let the (probably less frequent) use of "UTF-8" **automatically be substituted for `"UTF8"`** if someone calls a function's option that way?)

If I use file or path names which look right in Mathematica (indeed, they were made by a copy/paste operation via the clipboard from the Linux file browser to Mathematica), the non-ASCII characters in the strings become garbled through the standard handling of the command `Run`: However it should translate its parameter "command" such that all characters are translated in the right way to let the operating system sees them in its own encoding: **Exactly in the same way as if the OutputForm of the parameter would have been copied to the clipboard and it would have been pasted from there to a terminal.** Since my operating system speaks `"de_DE.UTF-8"`, the parameter *command* should be translated to the character encoding of the host system:

Für deutsch braucht man äÄöÖüÜ und ß.
Pour le français, il faut aussi áÁâÂÀàéÉêÊÈèùÙëËïÏæÆœŒçÇ et les guillemets « et ».
For other European languages other characters, accents, carons, macrons are customary with the Latin alphabet.

Since all these characters are legal in file- an directory names in Linux, **there should be a way to also pass them to a command with `Run`**.

**Is there a function for the outbound translation (i.e. from Mathematica to UTF8) such that the argument of Run[*command*] is treated that way such that the Linux system gets them transformed?**

Currently `Run["echo \"ähnlich, üblich oder örtlich\" > ~/file"]` produces a file with this content: `Ã¤hnlich, Ã¼blich oder Ã¶rtlich`

**How would one overload `Run` such that it accepts an additional parameter (or an option,  `CharacterEncoding->"UTF8"`) which it currently does not have?**

Note: A similar but different question about conversion of file *content* has been asked by me recently [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246628/how-to-convert-strings-from-mathematica-utf-8-to-linux-with-locale-de-de-utf). But this question is different because it deals with file names, not with their *content*.